# PHP: handle undefined exception

Tags: php

I have a device that sends data to url, depending on situations 3 sometimes 4 parameters are received, when i try to get data for 4th parameter using

```
$a = $_GET["xyz"];
```

> in the case when  "**xyz**"
>   does not exist the function

```
_GET['xyz'];
```

returns undefined. i tried using try catch and initialized **$a** to a empty string in **catch** part but it did not work either. How can that undefined exception be handled?

Comment: use isset() function;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4261200/998096

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
  if(isset($_GET["xyz"])) {
        $a = $_GET["xyz"];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if a parameter is passed in through the URL, you can use isset()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

This will check to see if the parameter exists

```
// This will evaluate to TRUE so the text will be printed.
if (isset($var)) {
    echo "This var is set so I will print.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary operator

```
$a=(isset($_GET["xyz"]))?$_GET["xyz"]:'';
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle such errors, you should use php's library function,

[set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

On having error such as undefined index, undefined variable etc.. will be handle by handleError function.

```
public function handleError($code,$message,$file,$line){
    // handling 
}
```

All the Best !!